# How can I push 3 or 4 variables into the array list in QML at a time

Tags: javascript, arrays, qml

I am new to qml and javascript technologies. I need sample example on push and pop operations on the array. For example, how can I push 3 variables into the array list in QML at a time. I want the output to be like below
[{"A001", 1, "Item1"}, {"A002", 2, "Item2"}].
I have started with sample code but could not able to complete the logic in Component.onCompleted.

```
Window {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480
title: qsTr("Hello World")

property var object: ({})
property var list: []

property string str1: "A001"
property int value1: 1
property string item1: "Item1"

property string str2: "A002"
property int value2: 2
property string item2: "Item2"

Component.onCompleted: {
    //1. Frame the object {str1, value1, item1}
    //2. Push to the array using push operation
    //3. The output of the array to be [{"A001", 1, "Item1"}]

    //4. Frame the object {str2, value2, item2}
    //5. Push to the array using push operation
    //6. The output of the array to be [{"A001", 1, "Item1"},{"A002", 2, "Item2"}]
    
    //7. Do pop operation on the array
    //8. The output of the array to be [{"A001", 1, "Item1"}]

    //9. Do pop operation on the array
    //10. The output of the array to be []
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want an array of objects. In javascript, objects are key/value pairs. So you have to create them something like this:

```
var obj1 = {"str": str1, "value": value1, "item": item1}
var obj2 = {"str": str2, "value": value2, "item": item2}
```

Then you can push or pop them onto your array:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(obj1);
arr.push(obj2);
arr.pop();
arr.pop();
```